# Cannot submit a form on php and mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a html form that i want to submit its data into a specific database in wamp using phpmyadmin, the connection is successfully done. However, the data cannot be submitted. I get this message after submitting the data in the form :

```
Successful connection
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\Ex\insert-data.php on line 11
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  136600  {main}( )   ..\insert-data.php:0
2   0.0023  144480  mysqli_query ( )    ..\insert-data.php:11
Error inserting new records!
```

My Code in 'insert-data.php'  is:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
 include('connect.php');
 $fname = $_POST['fname'];
 $lname = $_POST['lname'];

      $sqlinsert=
    "INSERTINTO`test`(`FName`,`LName`)VALUES('$fname','$lname')";

if(!mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqlinsert)){

 die('Error inserting new records!');
}
echo "1 record added to database";



}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>      



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<h1>Insert Data into DB</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="insert-data.php" >
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname"  />  
    <label>last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname"  />

    <input type="checkbox" name="check" />
    <input type="radio" name="radios" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"></button>

    </form>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Any idea? ....Thanks

Comment: Missing space in `INSERTINTO`.

Comment: Can you show the code inside connect.php page?

Comment: Use MySQLi properly! Prepare your statements! http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php . Also, another point when showing an error that has appeared please make clear which line is number 11. However, in the case your query string needs to be spaced

Comment: No,it has a space in my code ..but here by mistake appears like that ..

Comment: This is line 11 :if(!mysqli_query($dbconn,$sqlinsert)){

Comment: @LiamSorsby bro please read the error clearly. It says "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli," which means that first parameter in mysqli_query() which is $dbconn has the problem in it.

Comment: @Judy paste the whole page plz :)

Comment: sidenote: `<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />` that will always be true and will repost on page reloading. You should set your conditional statement to the submit button along with using `!empty()` as part of that conditional. A header redirect is better and using sessions and tokens to avoid that. You also have a syntax error here `<input type="submit" value="submit"></button>`

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes I apologise. I hold my hands up, your right. I am sorry. I seem to have missed that section. The irony. :-)

Comment: The code above is in insert-data.php

Comment: @Judy i want code from connect.php page also plz.

Comment: @Judy are you by any chance running mysql_connect() instead of mysqli_connect()?

Comment: you need to post your connection codes, replacing credentials with `xxx`. Edit: @LiamSorsby or PDO for that matter. Who knows ;-)

Comment: @LiamSorsby lol bro, exactly my thoughts :D

Comment: @LiamSorsby and you are right on that point.

Comment: I deleted </button> and tried it again the same warning.

Comment: you've been asked what to do and you didn't. This, about your db connection codes.

Comment: <?php
 $db_host="localhost";
 $db_username="root";
 $db_pass="";
 $db_name="test";

$dbconn = @mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die("Could not connect to MySQL");  
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("No database");

echo"Successful connection";
?>

Comment: Follow this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php  and fix your connect.php file.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes you were right :-)!

Comment: @LiamSorsby [it was indeed `mysql_` after all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592926/cannot-submit-a-form-on-php-and-myqli-query#comment51138385_31592926) Liam ;-) finally, *solved.* cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you posted your connection codes in comments (which belongs in your question I might add) being `mysql_` based.

You need to use `mysqli`

those different MySQL APIs do not intermix. You must use the same one from connection to query.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Example pulled from the manual:

```
<?php 
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

and remember to replace `$link` with `$dbconn` and your own credentials.

This doesn't help you:

```
die('Error inserting new records!');
```

this does:

```
or die(mysqli_error($dbconn));
```

---

Since you seem new to this, use prepared statements right away.

References:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Just for argument's sake, put a space between `INSERT` and `INTO`:

```
$sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO `test` (`FName`,`LName`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";
```

You seem to have made a reference to that in comments that they are seperated, but I said it anyway.

- Plus, try putting your connection/include on top of your conditional statement.

---

**Connection:**

Your connection should be this and replacing the `xxx` with your own credentials.

```
$db_host     = "xxx";
$db_username = "xxx";
$db_pass     = "xxx";
$db_name     = "xxx";

$dbconn = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") 
or die("Error".mysqli_error($dbconn));
```

and nothing else. No instances of `mysql_` at all.

Sidenote: `@` symbols are error suppressors. You can add them back in once everything is working.

---

Closing notes:

*Kudos to Liam (Sorsby).*

Comment: I corrected that .. I'm not getting the warning but still error inserting the records, I'm getting this instead :                                                 Successful connectionError inserting new records!

Comment: @Judy you need to find out why your query failed. consult http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  - add  `or die(mysqli_error($dbconn))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Thank you anyway...but there is no problem with the connection...the problem is about inserting the data .

Comment: @Judy reload my answer and look at error reporting and why your query is failing under **this does:**

Comment: Thanks a lot... this is what i wrote and it worked.
$dbconn = @mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name") or die("Error".@mysqli_error($dbconn));  
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("No database");

echo"Successful connection";

Comment: @Judy you also have `<input type="checkbox" name="check" />
    <input type="radio" name="radios" />` in your question but no related code for it in your SQL. If that is indeed part of it, you need to modify your question/code for it. I tested your code, no problems. Check to see if you haven't a restraint somewhere, that the column names have the right type and lengths. If your inputs have apostrophes, or anything else that MySQL will complain about, then that would be a contributing factor. I see no errors with what I posted as a solution.

Comment: @Judy the @ symbols in @mysqli_connect etc. **suppresses** errors. and you can't use `@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("No database");` - there should be **no** instances of `mysql_` whatsoever. Please go over the manual on connecting, as stated in my answer.

Comment: @Judy You're welcome Judy. I'm glad to see this was resolved, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Growing another cactus here :)?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, God love 'em :-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nice answer! Finally Solved. +1 from me. This is why I don't get rep. I can't be bothered with answers like this. Haha

Comment: @LiamSorsby Thank you Liam. I made a slight edit. See "Closing notes". *cheers* ;-)

Comment: Haha! Thank you very much ;-) haha

Comment: @LiamSorsby You're welcome Liam. You were the *crystal ball* on this one ;-)

Comment: Now onto the next one. Ha

Answer (score 0):

Use separated words like,

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`FName`,`LName`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname')";
```

Comment: OP stated in comments: *"No,it has a space in my code ..but here by mistake appears like that .. –  Judy 4 mins ago"*